# Remove zip code from address in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to identify and remove a zip code from a string that contains city, state, zip?

I will always have a city, state, zip in the following structure:

`"San Diego, CA 92115"`

I need to remove the zip code and only return

`"San Diego, CA"`

Comment: Just substring off the last 6 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the digits using

```js
let str = "San Diego, CA 92115";

// if the pincode is the only digit
console.log(str.replace(/\d+/, ''));

// if the pincode is only 5 digit always
console.log(str.replace(/\d{5}/, ''));
```

Comment: hi - thank you, but what regex would I use if the zipcode has a +4? such as 92115-4432?

Comment: You could use the regex \d{5}(?:-\d{4})?

Comment: you mean like this? `str.replace(  \d{5}(?:-\d{4}), '')` it's throwing me a syntax error :(

Comment: str.replace( /\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?/, '') should work for you

Answer (score 2):

As its a fixed format just remove all following & including the last space:

```
str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

Or if all Zips are 5 digits:

```
str = str.slice(0, -6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "San Diego, CA 92115";
str = str.replace(/ \d{5}$/, '');
```

`\d{5}` - means 5 digits, you can change this count of digits or just use `\d+` - any number of digits.

`$` - means you will remove digits only at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

When the provided string contains five digits at the end, optionally followed by spaces, this code will remove the digits and any spaces that may follow. If five digits are not detected, the original string will be used.

```
var s="San Diego, CA 92115";
var matches=s.match(/(.*)\d{5}\s*$/);
alert(matches?matches[1]:s);
```